# Predict Logistf

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm using a R package called logistf to make a Logistc Regression and I saw that there's no predict function for new data in this package and predict package does not work with this, so I found a code that show how making this with new data:

```
fit<-logistf(Tax ~ L20+L24+L28+L29+L31+L32+L33+L36+S10+S15+S16+S17+S20, data=trainData) 
betas <- coef(fit)
X <- model.matrix(fit, data=testData)
probs <- 1 / (1 + exp(-X %*% betas))
```

I want to make a cross validation version with this using **fit$predict** and the probabilities that **probs** generate for me. Has anyone ever done something like this before?

Other thing that I want to know is about **fit$predict** I'm making a binary logistic regression, and this function returns many values, are these values from class 0 or 1, how can I know this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the code that you wrote works perfectly, there is a concise way of getting the same results seemingly:

```
    brglm_model <- brglm(formula = response ~ predictor , family = "binomial", data = train )
brglm_pred <- predict(object = brglm_model, newdata = test , type = "response")
```

About the CV, you have to write a few lines of code I guess:

```
#Setting the number of folds, and number of instances in each fold
n_folds <- 5 
fold_size <- nrow(dataset) %/% 5 
residual <- nrow(dataset) %% 5

#label the instances based on the number of folds
cv_labels <- c(rep(1,fold_size),rep(2,fold_size), rep(3,fold_size), rep(4,fold_size), rep(5,fold_size), rep(5,residual))

# the error term would differ based on each threshold value
t_seq <- seq(0.1,0.9,by = 0.1)
index_mat <- matrix(ncol = (n_folds+1) , nrow = length(t_seq))
index_mat[,1] <- t_seq 

# the main loop for calculation of the CV error on each fold
for (i in 1:5){
        train <- dataset %>% filter(cv_labels != i) 
        test <- dataset %>% filter(cv_labels == i )

        brglm_cv_model <- brglm(formula = response_var ~ . , family = "binomial", data = train )
        brglm_cv_pred <- predict(object = brglm_model, newdata = test , type = "response")

        # error formula that you want, e.g. misclassification
        counter <- 0 

        for (treshold in t_seq ) {
               counter <- counter + 1 
               conf_mat <- table( factor(test$response_var) , factor(brglm_cv_pred>treshold, levels = c("FALSE","TRUE") )) 

               sen <- conf_mat[2,2]/sum(conf_mat[2,])

               # other indices can be computed as follows 
               #spec <- conf_mat[1,1]/sum(conf_mat[1,])
               #prec <- conf_mat[2,2]/sum(conf_mat[,2])
               #F1 <- (2*prec * sen)/(prec+sen)
               #accuracy <- (conf_mat[1,1]+conf_mat[2,2])/sum(conf_mat)

               #here I am only interested in sensitivity
               index_mat[counter,(i+1)] <- sen 

        }

}

# final data.frame would be the mean of sensitivity over each threshold value 
final_mat <- matrix(nrow = length(t_seq), ncol = 2 )
final_mat[,1] <- t_seq 
final_mat[,2] <- apply(X = index_mat[,-1] , MARGIN = 1 , FUN = mean)
final_mat <- data.frame(final_mat)
colnames(final_mat) <- c("treshold","sensitivity")

#why not having a look at the CV-sensitivity of the model over threshold values?
ggplot(data = final_mat) + 
        geom_line(aes(x = treshold, y = sensitivity ), color = "blue")
```